# Set column width on th, td, or both?

Tags: css, css-tables, tablecolumn

Using CSS, I want to specify certain widths for columns in a table. Should I set the widths in the thead (on the th's), in the tbody (on the td's)...or both?

Comment: Are you looking for a uniformly spaced table? If so, I'd use cell padding: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_cellpadding.asp

Or are you looking for a dynamic table (where you can set specific rows' or columns' sizes, I would)?

Answer (score 1):

The `<th>`'s would be the best place to set the width, because it is iterated only once.

Save your client a few bytes.

The other `<td>`'s will shape out implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use colgroup tag to explicate cloumns style.
e.g

```
<table>
 <colgroup>
  <col style="color:red;width:100px">
  <col style="background-color:yellow">
 </colgroup>
 <tr>
  <th>this will be red and width is 100px</th>
  <th>this will be yellow</th>
 </tr>
</table>
```